# If I draw my Critical Miss card, can I apply its effect so as to mitigate it?

Tags: gloomhaven

I don't have the rules in front of me so I may be using different terminology to that used in the rules.

Suppose I am playing as the Scoundrel and have taken the perk that allows me to add "(draw another card and) +1" battle cards to my deck. Now suppose I make an "Attack 3" on a monster. I draw one of my "(draw another card and) +1" cards. I duly draw another card, and it is my Critical Miss card.

Am I allowed to apply the effect of the Critical Miss card first, then apply the +1 after that? In other words, in what order do I do things?

- first multiply by 0 (for the Critical Miss), giving 0, then add 1, giving 1?
- first add 1 (giving 4), then multiply by 0, giving 0?
- my choice of the above?

Or is there no ordering to be done and it's a blank "if the Critical Miss card is drawn and it applies to the attack, then the attack deals no damage to the opponent, no matter what other cards were drawn"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've possibly already answered this in a roundabout way [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/40560/do-i-retaliate-against-a-missed-attack/40561#40561).

The short answer is none of your options.  The attack did no damage.

There is no such thing as a "miss" or "critical miss" card in Gloomhaven. The word 'miss' does not appear anywhere in the rules.  It is a 'null' card.

from page 11 of rules

> A “Null” symbol means that no damage is done by the attack.

If you pull rolling modifiers and then draw the null card you did no damage.  If the base value of the attack and any other rolling modifiers do not come into play.

Its important to make the distinction between damage and effects.  if you attack added poison or you pulled a rolling wound these are still applied as these are not damage and the attack didn't miss as there is no such thing.

Comment: Another way to think about it is to apply the cards (and other effects) in order. `Attack 3` (3 damage) `Poison` (4 damage) `Rolling +1` (5 damage) `Miss` (0 damage, stop).

Comment: Remember though its not a 'miss'  its a null   I think the terminology is important here to avoid confusion.

Comment: I would have to check what the book refers to the card as, but it would not surprise me that most players refer to it as "miss."

Comment: You're correct.  My own playing group keep saying miss so I keep correcting.  The word miss makes is sound like you don't apply status effects when you do.  its important to call it a Null and not a miss.

Comment: Sure, sure. For my (one) group it was just looking at the rules and finding, "oh, you still apply status effects on a miss." For my other group, I think everyone had played before, but hilariously one person's first group had done ***everything*** wrong. The only specific I remember now was that ranged enemies would pick a focus, move away, then *pick a new focus* for the attack. But there were like seven or eight things we had to correct. We still regularly forget to give out Bad Idea Cards (Battle Goals), though.